# Struggling to display a button

Tags: java

I've previously made a button before but this is my first time trying to make it reusable for a project i'm working on. When i did it before i ran into no issues as it was all in one class but now with it being spread across a few classes I can't do `this.add(button1)`. As you can see I currently have `add(button1)` but it doesn't add it to the screen what can i change to add it to the screen?

p.s i don't mind about it not doing anything right now I just want it to be on the screen i can do the rest after that! Also this is my first time using stack overflow so sorry if I've formatted this message incorrectly.

I've tried a lot of things but not found any solutions - all of my attempts where hopeless ahah so not much i can add to what I've tried. Any help would be amazing thanks.

```java
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Main { 
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Buttons"); 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Mainmenu menu = new Mainmenu();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setSize(650,500); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.add(menu); 
    } 
} 

import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Mainmenu extends JPanel{ 
    private button button1; 

    Mainmenu () { 
        setLayout(null); 
        button1 = new button(50, 50, 50, 50, "game1", Color.red, Color.CYAN); 
        add(button1); 
    } 

} 

import javax.swing.JButton; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Font; 

public class button { 
    JButton tempButton = new JButton(); 

    public button (int x, int y, int width, int height, String buttonName, Color text, Color background) { 
        tempButton.setText(buttonName);  
        tempButton.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans",Font.BOLD,25)); 
        tempButton.setForeground(text); 
        tempButton.setBackground(background); 
        tempButton.setFocusable(false); 
        tempButton.setBounds(x, y, width, height); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a null layout?

Comment: This doesn't reflect what is happening. You cannot `add` button1 because it is not a `Component`. You shouldn't be extending anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a static method.

```
public static JButton button (int x, int y, int width, int height, String buttonName, Color text, Color background) { 
    JButton tempButton = new JButton();
    tempButton.setText(buttonName);  
    tempButton.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans",Font.BOLD,25)); 
    tempButton.setForeground(text); 
    tempButton.setBackground(background); 
    tempButton.setFocusable(false); 
    tempButton.setBounds(x, y, width, height); 
    return tempButton;
}
```

That way you'll return a formatted button.

The call to "setBounds" is really a bad practice. Don't use null layout and dont call setBounds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that your `Button` class doesn't extends `JButton` like your `Menu` class, to make it work you can make it extend `JButton` or add a `getMethod` to return your `button` attribute.